# Code Compilation errors with poco-1.8.1

Tags: string, compiler-errors, poco-libraries

I have built a windows service using poco "poco-1.8.1".
I am using various features of poco like services, json, httpclientsession, httprequest etc.

While building the code I get errors like:

```
1>. . . \libs\poco-1.8.1\foundation\include\poco\metaprogramming.h(104): error C2059: syntax error: 'string'
1>. . . \libs\poco-1.8.1\foundation\include\poco\metaprogramming.h(108): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Poco::TypeWrapper<T>' being compiled
1>. . . \libs\poco-1.8.1\foundation\include\poco\metaprogramming.h(104): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>. . . \libs\poco-1.8.1\foundation\include\poco\metaprogramming.h(114): error C2059: syntax error: 'string'
1>. . . \libs\poco-1.8.1\foundation\include\poco\metaprogramming.h(118): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Poco::TypeWrapper<const T>' being compiled
1>. . . \libs\poco-1.8.1\foundation\include\poco\metaprogramming.h(114): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>. . . \libs\poco-1.8.1\foundation\include\poco\metaprogramming.h(124): error C2059: syntax error: 'string'
1>. . . \libs\poco-1.8.1\foundation\include\poco\metaprogramming.h(128): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Poco::TypeWrapper<const T&>' being compiled
1>. . . \libs\poco-1.8.1\foundation\include\poco\metaprogramming.h(124): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>. . . \libs\poco-1.8.1\foundation\include\poco\metaprogramming.h(134): error C2059: syntax error: 'string'
1>. . . \libs\poco-1.8.1\foundation\include\poco\metaprogramming.h(138): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Poco::TypeWrapper<T&>' being compiled
1>. . . \libs\poco-1.8.1\foundation\include\poco\metaprogramming.h(134): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>. . . \libs\poco-1.8.1\net\include\poco\net\httpmessage.h(139): error C2059: syntax error: 'string'

1>. . . \libs\poco-1.8.1\net\include\poco\net\httpmessage.h(139): error C2059: syntax error: 'string'
1>. . . \libs\poco-1.8.1\net\include\poco\net\httpmessage.h(139): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>. . . \libs\poco-1.8.1\foundation\include\poco\metaprogramming.h(104): error C2059: syntax error: 'string'
1>. . . \libs\poco-1.8.1\foundation\include\poco\metaprogramming.h(108): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Poco::TypeWrapper<T>' being compiled
1>. . . \libs\poco-1.8.1\foundation\include\poco\metaprogramming.h(104): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>. . . \libs\poco-1.8.1\foundation\include\poco\metaprogramming.h(114): error C2059: syntax error: 'string'
```

Note ignore the ". . . \" in the path above as I have removed absolute path  before posting here.

I am not using the metaprogramming part of poco directly.
What might be the cause of these errors and how to rectify it?